# How to display a list of notification message in a panel

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, notifications

I have my program that notifies via `MsgBox` when a product is soon to be expire and reaches its critical level. It is annoying if many `MsgBox` will appear. I just want to make a list of notification messages inside a Panel, like Facebook's notifications.

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStockNotif.Click
    timerStockNotif.Stop()
    Dim critical, stocks, medName, unit As String

    Try
        SQL = "SELECT critical_level, medicine_name, stocks_on_hand, unit FROM medicine_info"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While dr.Read
            critical = dr("critical_level")
            stocks = dr("stocks_on_hand")
            medName = dr("medicine_name")
            unit = dr("Unit")

            If stocks <= critical Then

                MsgBox("The product " & medName & " " & unit & " has only " & stocks & " stocks left. Please call your supplier to order more " & medName & " " & unit & ".", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Product at critical level")
                If MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
                    btnStockNotif.Visible = False
                End If
            End If

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue? Yes, msgbox's are annoying

Comment: @Drew I just want to make a list of notification message inside a `Panel`. Just like Facebook's notifications.

Comment: maybe have a datagridview or listbox and bubble them up

Comment: I have no idea what FaceBook looks like, but you can dock a DataGridView to the bottom of the form and post issues of all sorts there.  Even tag informational ones with an expiry, have the thing open and auto close (like VS Error window can).

Comment: ...of course for something like a stock management system, you could associate a low stock level indicator *in* the data display quite easily

Comment: I know how to insert data in DataGridView from database. But, is it possible to insert data that is concatenated just like on the `MsgBox` above?

Comment: Why do you need a long message?  If there is a cell with "Low" or "Critically Low" and perhaps a rose/pink color - in the same row as "NZT 2130", what more needs to be said?  Wouldnt it be repeating what the user can already see?  BTW, `insert data in DataGridView` is suboptimal - use a DataTable and the Low Stock indicator can be an `Expression Column` which does the calc for you are posts the result.